# PostgreSQL: when create variable-sized type by C, error about "compressed data corrupted"

Tags: c, postgresql, psql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to create a data type in PostgreSQL 10.4 using C language.

I've defined a SET type in C, which structure is as follows. The data attribute is a variable-sized array.

```
typedef struct intSet
{
    int32   length;
    int32   data[FLEXIBLE_ARRAY_MEMBER];
} intSet;
```

when I set the internallength in .source file to VARIABLE, as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE intSet (
   internallength = VARIABLE,
   input = intset_in,
   output = intset_out
```

I've got the error msg like this, while when I set the `internallength` in a actual value, everything seems ok.

```
psql: intset.sql:89: ERROR: compressed data is corrupted
LINE 3:    ('MongoDB','{2,4}'),
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I may came up with two possible points:

1, To set the "internallength" as "VARIABLE", you would need to set "storage" option as stated in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/storage-toast.html

2, Have you defined your input and output function in proper way? This include:

- Declare function in format of "PGDLLEXPORT Datum *XXXX*(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)";
- Create function in format of "Datum *XXXX*(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)"
- For input function you would need return a pointer to the structure, also you need to allocate memory, either from malloc or by stack.
- For output function, it is need to be returned with text format, psprintf is suggested.

Hope it helps...

Comment: may I ask the difference between declare function and create function? I do use the format of  Datum XXXX(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) in .c file in C language, and use the format of CREATE FUNCTION input(cstring) in .source file.

Comment: I find that PGDLLEXPORT is used in Windows right? while I'm using the Linux operation systems.

Comment: Yep I'm using windows, not sure for linux but also need to do in a similar way. Due to the fact that setting internallength in a actual value will fix the problem. I think first you need to try setting proper value of storage option, and then due to the toast function is applied, you would have to deal with the length of the data each time you retrieve and write it...... I can't remember but the toast data have to set the data length when input, and when retrieving, the data length can also be achieved by VARSIZE_ANY() function....